# Convert all characters to dec or hex HTML code equivalent

Tags: php, html, encoding

Is there a way I can convert ALL characters, including regular ones, using PHP to something like this:

```
&\#38; &\#233; &\#224; &\#231; &\#60;
```

When I say regular characters I mean to say chars like "ABCD123!@#$", etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this one liner.

1. Split string into a proper array.
2. Iterate over characters getting their ordinal value.
3. Join with the entity pattern.

```
echo '&#' . join(';&#', array_map('ord', str_split($str))) . ';';
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WfUrV9).

Also, you said you wanted to convert the characters to their hex equivalent, but none of your values appear to be hex, unless it's a coincidence and there are just no `a-f` in your example.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways. One is

```
join('', array_map(create_function('$c', 'return "&#".ord($c).";";'), str_split($string)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Piggy-backing on Alex's/Anomie's answer, to get full Unicode support, you could use the package at http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/ to do:

```
'&#' . join(';&#', utf8ToUnicode($str) . ';'
```